# Set position of polygons and paths in d3

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have several external SVG files I want to read in and position. Some of the SVG files are polygons, others are paths. For most of them, I specific a random amount to translate the files when I read them in. But I want to specifically assign a position for a couple of the shapes. ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Amyunimus/2xzc0Lgf/10/)).

```js
var width = 300, height = 300;
var sampleSVG = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr( {width: width, height: height} );

var shapes = [
{url:"https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2467665/shapes/shapes-01.svg", number: 1, color: 'red'},
{url:"https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2467665/shapes/shapes-02.svg", number: 2, color: 'yellow'},
{url:"https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2467665/shapes/shapes-03.svg", number: 3, color: 'orange'},
{url:"https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2467665/shapes/shapes-04.svg", number: 4, color: 'green'},
{url:"https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2467665/shapes/shapes-05.svg", number: 5, color: 'blue'},
{url:"https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2467665/shapes/shapes-06.svg", number: 6, color: 'purple'},
{url:"https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2467665/shapes/shapes-07.svg", number: 7, color: 'red'},
{url:"https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2467665/shapes/shapes-08.svg", number: 8, color: 'orange'}];

var q = queue();
shapes.forEach(function(shape) { 
  q.defer(d3.xml, shape.url, "image/svg+xml"); 
});

q.awaitAll(function (error, results) {
    sampleSVG.selectAll('g.shape').data(shapes)
    // g tag is created for positioning the shape at random location
    .enter().append('g').attr('class', 'shape')
        .attr('transform', function () {
        return 'translate(' + Math.random() * (w - 50) + ',' + Math.random() * (h - 50) + ')'
    })
        .each(function (d, i) {
        // the loaded svg file is then appended inside the g tag
        this.appendChild(results[i].documentElement);
        d3.select(this).select('svg').select("*")
        .attr("stroke", function () {return d.color;})
        .attr('transform', function () {
            if (d.number > 6) {
               var newX = 200,
                   newY = 200;

               //This is where I want to set the position
               return 'scale(0.3) translate(0,0)'}

            else {return 'scale(0.1)'}

        ;})
    })
});
```

Basically, I want the shapes to have different random positions except for two shapes (those with `d.number > 6`) which I want to appear at (200,200).

Is there a way to either reset `translate` and then run it again with new amounts, or specifically set the position of both paths and polygons?

Comment: Unclear: Are you asking to adjust the `transform` attribute of the `<g class="shape">` from within `.each(function(d, i){ ... })`?

Comment: If I set the position from within ```.each```, all the shapes take on the same position, which I don't want, which is why I set the random translation outside it. But I want to control the position of individual shapes based on some criteria (here ```d.number > 6```), which is why I thought I could do it within ```.each```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still unclear, but I think this is what you're looking for:

```
q.awaitAll(function (error, results) {
  sampleSVG.selectAll('g.shape')
    .data(shapes)
  .enter()
    .append('g')
      .attr('class', 'shape')
      .each(function (d, i) {
        // the loaded svg file is then appended inside the g tag
        this.appendChild(results[i].documentElement);

        d3.select(this).select('svg').select("*")
          .attr("stroke", d.color);
      })
      .attr('transform', function (d, i) {
        // In general, in here we're setting the transform of a <g>, which contains an svg. So:
        if (d.number > 6) {
          var newX = 200,
              newY = 200;

          // What you return here will scale and translate the <g> (and the svg inside it)
          return 'scale(0.3) translate(0,0)';
        }
        else {
          return 'translate(' + Math.random() * (w - 50) + ',' + Math.random() * (h - 50) + ') scale(0.1)';
        }
      });
});
```

Comment: Hmm, no now they all have the same position. Basically, I want the shapes to have random positions except for 2 of them (those with ```number > 6```) to appear at (200,200).

Comment: @Amyunimus I modified the code (brought back the random positioning bit). Here's a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2xzc0Lgf/11/).